# phpmyadmin cannot Export procedure

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I export MySQL database using phpMyAdmin it exports all the table data perfectly but does not exports `PROCEDURES` properly. What I got is:

```
DELIMITER $$
--
-- Procedures
--
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_users_get`$$
$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_users_save`$$
$$
```

There should be more code like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_user_get`......
```

till the procedure ends.

Can anyone help me to successfully export database from phpMyAdmin?

Comment: [Problem with DELIMITER in phpmyadmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132420/error-when-creating-a-trigger-in-mysql-5-5-27/13133843#13133843).

Comment: I get the same output when the "DEFINER" attribute of the stored procedure doesn't match the IP address of the machine I am using to connect to the database. To overcome this, I now only create/edit my procedures and functions from within the phpmyadmin installation provided by my web host as that ensures the DEFINER is always set to username@localhost. Unfortunately, this means I cannot view the body of a routine using external tools like MySQL Workbench, but at least I can always get to them from any machine using phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is no useful thing I found. It seems that there is a bug in phpMyAdmin. The next day I have tried to access it and its showing me the procedures. I'm not sure what happened but May be its because I've changed `delimiter`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using adminer ( http://www.adminer.org/ ) as an alternative to phpmyadmin.
Phpmyadmin has become really bloted and it's often buggy, slow, and hey; you even get smaller dumps with adminer!

The interface is austere, but once you get used to it it's fantastic.
my 2c :)